# How to digitally sign PDF documents in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a native library to digitally sign a PDF document?

Comment: What do you mean by native? Do you mean one written in ruby, or one that is native for a particular OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package [here](http://www.kryptokoder.com/signwithext.html) seems to provide an extension for signing PDFs with Ruby. It isn't free, but it looks like it provides a native ruby interface.

Here's how to use if in ruby (after it's been installed):

```
require 'mypdfsigner'
include MyPDFSigner

inputPath = "/tmp/input.pdf"
outputPath = "/tmp/output.pdf"
location = "Chicago"
reason = "Demo"
contactInfo = "+1 555-555-5555"
certify = false   # not supported yet
visible = true
title = "Signing with MyPDFSigner"
author = "KryptoKoder"
subject = "Ruby Extension"
keywords = "PKCS#12, MyPDFSigner, PDF"
confFile = ""   # defaults to /usr/local/mypdfsigner/mypdfsigner.conf if empty
timestamp = true

puts mypdfsigner_sign(inputPath, outputPath, location, reason, contactInfo, certify, visible, title, author, subject, keywords, confFile, timestamp)
```

There's also a command line interface, so you can script it if needed, as well as a desktop app.

Comment: Thank you @cdeszaq. As I can see it is not a common installation like "gem instal mypdfsigner" right? Do you know why it is that way?

Comment: @RicardoAcras - I'm not sure why, but I would guess that it has to do with it not being free, as well as having a desktop app and command-line scripting abilities. You would have to ask the company to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would us an iText as it can construct PDFs and sign them too ...